# Calculus, Pattern

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, fractional-calculus, pochhammer-symbol

A quick question, anyone recognizes how they are related? 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \left[\int_{\epsilon}^\infty (1-e^{-t})^{-\alpha-1} (-t)^\beta e^{-t} dt\right] = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(\alpha+1)_j}{j!} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \int_\epsilon^\infty e^{-(j+1)t} t^\beta dt
\end{equation}
where the $(a)_k = a(a+1)\cdots(a+k-1)$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

My best guess is taylor series, but I couldn't derive the general formula somehow....

Comment: I believe they expanded $(1-e^{-t})^{-\alpha-1}$ with the binomial series and then swapped the integral and sum operators.

Comment: @Jam Hey, I have double checked, and found it to be Newton's generalized binomial theorem! Thanks a lot for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, this is just the generalized binomial theorem which can be interpreted as the Maclaurin expansion of the following:

$$(1+t)^\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom\alpha kt^k$$

where $\displaystyle\binom\alpha k=\frac{(\alpha-k+1)_k}{k!}$, replacing $\alpha\to-\alpha-1$ and $t\to-e^{-t}$ to get

$$(1-e^{-t})^{-\alpha-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-\alpha-1}k(-1)^ke^{-kt}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\alpha+1)_k}{k!}e^{-kt}$$

It would also appear that there is a missing $(-1)^\beta$ and the sum index should start at $j=0$.

Comment: Ah yes, I am sorry for not mentioning the $(-1)^\beta$. It has some sort of relationship (not your issue). But regarding the sum index should start at $j=0$, I double checked the proof and found that it is indeed $j=0$, the book I copied from has some errors. Thanks for being so observant and sorry for wasting bit of your time!